# evaluate function in AngularJS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm iterating over a list with dates (jobs.submitted):

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardController as dashboard">


<div ng-repeat="job in dashboard.jobs | filter: {status: 'started'}" class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-3">{{job.submitted}}</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to calculate a duration:

```
(new Date(job.submitted)) - (new Date(job.completed))
```

If I put this directly into the expression I get a syntax error (I guess angularJS doesn't understand the Date object).

If I put it into a function, the function in the controller, the function never evaluates:

```
{{dashboard.getDuration(job)}}
```

is blank.

What is the best way of tackling this?

Comment: Did you add `getDuration` as a property on your `jobs` object? Or is it on your controller? Is `dashboard` your controller? We need more information.

Comment: It is really easier to help you if a jsfiddle is provided. Have you tried to put `Date` into `$scope` (`$scope.Date = Date`) or just `{{ jobs.getDuration(job) }}` (assuming you did `this.jobs.getDuration = function ...`)?

Comment: `dashboard.jobs` seems to be an array, without a function `getDuration` in there. So, looks like you need to add getDuration into `$scope` or into `this` in your controller and then use controller As syntax.

Comment: things like this should be done in the controller or data service, not in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$scope.getDays=function getDays(toDate, fromDate, isNegetiveAllowed) {
    toDate=new Date(toDate);
    fromDate=new Date(fromDate);
    return Math.round((toDate - fromDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="job in dashboard.jobs | filter: {status: 'started'}" class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-3">{{ getDays(job.completed,job.submitted) }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expose the function via _this_ (I'm not using $scope - https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y031). Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That should be done in controller not in view.
You can try this way:

In view:

> {{getJobDiiff(job)}}

In controller:

```
$scope.getJobDiiff= function(job){
//chage dates in timestamp 
var timestamp1 = new Date(job.submitted).getTime();
var timestamp2 = new Date(job.completed)).getTime();
var diff = timestamp1 - timestamp2;
var newDate = new Date (diff);
return newDate;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Here is one way](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/1/)

```
var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/12/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```